# Calculate an undefined size (n) determinant

Tags: linear-algebra

Simply put, not quite sure where to even start with something like this..

Calculate the n-sized determinant
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ReXVh.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way in my opinion, but requires more knowledge, is to recognize it as the product of the eigenvalues.  View the matrix as $\text{Ones}_{n\times n} + (n-1)I$ where $\text{Ones}_{n\times n}$ is the $n\times n$ matrix consisting of all $1$'s.

Note $\text{Ones}_{n\times n}$ has eigenvalue $0$ with geometric multiplicity $n-1$ (*since it is clearly rank1*) and eigenvalue $n$ (*since the others are zero and the trace is $n$ which should have been the sum of the eigenvalues*) with geometric multiplicity $1$.

$(n-1)I$ obviously has eigenvalue $n-1$ with geometric multiplicity $n$, no effort required, and can use the same eigenbasis as $\text{Ones}_{n\times n}$ since this is the identity matrix we are talking about.

It follows then that your matrix has eigenvalue $n-1$ with geometric multiplicity $n-1$ and eigenvalue $2n-1$ with geometric multiplicity $1$.  The determinant is then:

$$(2n-1)(n-1)^{n-1}$$

Comment: The $2n$ eigenvalue should be $2n-1$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass good catch.